# Android app session timeout

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want my application to maintain the user session,

It will keep me in home screen until define minutes, after that it should redirect to launcher activity (or login screen).

Is there any defined way in manifest file? or in any configuration?

I tried with my own custom code but ended up with few other impact on my app.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any such stuff in manifest file, Whats the impact you had with custom code? My guess is create a Timer, and then call finish, and start another activity